# Best method to analyse count data for several different categories

Tags: mixed-model, count-data

During a sustained attention task, participants were occasionally asked what they were thinking and to press a number indicating their current state of focus. Each instance asked the same question ("characterise your current focus") and there were 5 possible responses (1 = on task, 2 = distracted, 3 = nonalert, etc). I want to explore whether there's a difference between two conditions on the numbers of response for each category. I thought it'd be OK to use mixed models with the following basic model, with n being the counts of responses:

(n ~ condition * probe.type + ( 1 | subject)...)

Are mixed models OK for this, or should I be using something like a Poisson model?

Comment: You want to look into multinomial logistic models. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082396/multinomial-logistic-multilevel-models-in-r. Also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/c5.mxl.html for using the `mlogit` package.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I decided to follow those links and conducted a series of binomials.